# C++ сокеты: лишние данные

Tags: сокеты, c++

Здраствуйте.

Есть сервер, который работает с каждым клиентом в новом потоке, раньше таких проблем с сокетами не возникало, и что может быть их причиной - неясно.
Если клиент посылает строку `"hello world"`, то она отображается нормально, а если послать строку `"hello wo"`, то сервер выводит в консоль `"hello woH"`.

Функция чтения на сервере:

```
void read() {
    int bytes_read = 0;
    char buf[255];
    do {
        bytes_read = recv(this->s, buf, 255, 0);
        if(bytes_read) {
            printf("%s\n", buf);
        }
    } while(bytes_read);
    // остальной код закомментирован
}
```

Код функции клиента:

```
int main() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(4040);
    if(connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        cout << "error: " << errno << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    char *str = "hello wo";
    int i = send(sock, str, strlen(str), 0);
    close(sock);
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Сначала я использовал telnet, но решил написать простой клиент, т.к. думал, что это telnet прикалывается. Также интересно, что клиент нормально принимает данные от сервера.

Компилятор: g++

OS: Ubuntu

**UPD:**
Также непонятно, почему функция `printf()` не выводит строки, если нет в конце символа `'\n'`, например: `printf("test");` - не работает, а `printf("test\n");` - работает.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь вы столкнулись с типичным примером [неопределенного поведения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (оно же [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), в данном случае это *зависимость поведения программы* ***от состояния памяти***.

Содержимое локального массива `char buf[255];` не определено. Длина строки языка Си (это те `char []` , что передаем в `strlen()`, `printf()` и т.п.) определяется наличием **двоичного нуля** (байта с значением 0x00).

В свою очередь, функция `recv(this->s, buf, 255, 0)` читает в `buf` максимум 255 байт, возвращает количество реально прочитанных байт, но **никогда не заносит 0x00 после прочитанных данных**.

Очевидно, что  в вашем случае buf[8] случайно оказался равен 'W' (результат состояния стека ранее вызванных функций), а buf[9] (и наверное дальше тоже) нулем.

Это объясняет наблюдаемую картину при печати buf.

Поэтому пишите так:

```
...
bytes_read = recv(this->s, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);
if (bytes_read > 0) {  // recv() возвращает -1 при ошибках (см. man 3 recv)
  buf[bytes_read] = 0; 
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  fflush(stdout); /* а это ответ на UPD
                     вообще-то нужен только если нет \n в конце
                     или вывод идет не на терминал, а в pipe 
                     (или файл, который смотрите, например, tail -f)
                  */
}
...
```

Обратите внимание, что в вашем случае читать надо на 1 байт меньше, чем размер выделенного буфера,  чтобы оставить место для завершающего строку нуля, который сами пишем после вызова `recv()`.

Answer (score -1):

`char buf[255];` замените на `char buf[255] = {0};`, и будет Вам счастье. =)
А еще лучше перед `recv` затирайте буфер нулями.

Comment: Точно, спасибо.